# Counting all line features that overlap specific one from different shapefile

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, overlapping-features, feature-count

I have two shapefiles: 'Lines' and 'Base-line'. One attribute inside 'Base-line' is the number of 'Lines' features overlapping that specific 'Base-line' feature. It basically represents the number of tubes inside the main pipeline.

A 'Lines' feature can be overlapped to a chain of many consecutive 'Base-line' features.

I need to fill the attribute in the 'Base-line' features after I trace all the 'Lines' over the already traced 'Base-line'.

The total number of 'Lines' overlapping the specific 'Base-line' will then be used by a Virtual layer to create and display labels for each 'Base-line'.

Both shapefiles share a common key representing the coordinates of the geometry.

I tried using something like

```
aggregate(layer:='LINES_9e784a1c_48d8_4510_a6a5_20967c6dff6c',
          aggregate:='concatenate',
          expression:=count("KEY"),
          concatenator:='',
          filter:=intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent))
          )
```

But I think it would only work if the 'Lines' features have already been traced before the 'Base-line' (which is not possible). Any suggestions?

UPDATE

[image]

Example: there are 3 BASE_LINE features. Two LINE features are overlapping the first and then they proceed in different directions to overlap different BASE_LINE features.

This is what I get using

```
array_length(overlay_crosses( 'CAVI', $id))
```

[image]

Where CAVI are the LINES.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression on the baseline layer and replace 'lines' with the name of your lines-layer (works for QGIS 3.16+):

```
array_length(overlay_crosses( 'lines', $id))
```

*Screenshot: counting the number of red lines that cross each black baseline. For visualization purpose, here the expression is used directly in the label field, but you can use the same expression with field calculator to create a new field:*

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried a couple of ways to use this function but I always get 'false'.

I tried both writing only the layer name or the full name I find in properties 
overlay_crosses(layer:='LINES_707e57a2_4492_40b8_b982_55e7327b98e4').

Comment: whicht QGIS version? It must be 3.16 or later. Did you use the whole expression? `array_length(overlay_crosses( 'lines', $id))`

Comment: Yes, I opened the project with 3.16 and tried to update the field using the whole expression but I get zero.

I posted a picture with an example

Comment: Did you also try using the field calculator? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=field%20calculator#using-the-field-calculator Can you post a screenshot showing the lines + the layet panel with the names of the layers?

Comment: I see: your lines do not **cross** the baseline, they at best touch it. Even that might not be the case. Try using `overlay_touches` instead of `overlay_crosses` or extend your lines a bit, using `geometry by expression` with the function `extend`  https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=extend#extend then convert multi- to singleparts

Comment: the lines are snapped over each base-line. but one line might be snapped over multiple base-lines and I need each base-line to count every single line snapped on top of itself.